# Convergence of the Real analysis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The question is find the Fourier series of "|cost| for all t". I already found the fourier series

But now the question asks " At which values of $x$, does the series fail to converge to ? To what values does it converge at those points? "

So what to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will converge for all $x$; the function is Lipschitz continuous, and so its Fourier series converges everywhere. (see, for instance, [the answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70036/lipschitz-continuity-and-holder-continuity-helps-fourier-series-to-converge))

Comment: That means this series do not fail to converge is it BaronVT?

Comment: Right, it does not fail to converge anywhere.